# jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget-Cant able to apply in one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using this jQuery UI Multiselect Widget  script: http://runnable.com/UgMdJqspu4chAAAP/how-to-create-jquery-ui-multiselect-widget in asp.net.I have one child page with master page.While i am applying this control by default its applying to all `dropdownlist`.I want to apply for a single `Dropdownlist`. Can anybody help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        /*
        define global variable,
        and store message container element.
        */
        var warning = $(".message");

        $('select').multiselect(
        {
            /*
            The name of the effect to use when the menu opens.
            To control the speed as well, pass in an array
            */
            show: ["slide", 1000],
            /*
            The name of the effect to use when the menu closes.
            To control the speed as well, pass in an array
            */
            hide: ["slide", 1000],
            /*
            Either a boolean value denoting whether or not to display the header,
            or a string value.
            If you pass a string,
            the default "check all", "uncheck all", and "close"
            links will be replaced with the specified text.
            */
            header: "Choose only TEN items!",
            /*
            Fires when a checkbox is checked or unchecked,
            we are using this option to restrict,
            user to select no more than 3 option
            */
            click: function (e) {
                if ($(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length > 10) {
                    warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("You can only check three checkboxes!");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    warning.addClass("success").removeClass("error").html("Check a few boxes.");
                }
            }
            /*
            .multiselectfilter()
            Initialize filtering on any of your multiselects
            by calling multiselectfilter() on the widget.
            */
        }).multiselectfilter();
    });
</script>
```

In `$('select').multiselect()` while i am passing my `dropdown-list Id` then this control is not working.Only its working while giving `'select'`and simultaneously its applying to all `dropdown-list`. but i want to apply in one `dropdown-list`.Can anyone suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ID it should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#example").multiselect();
});
```

Reference link below is using the same plugin, Can you check your browser console for any javascript errors ?

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget